# UIView backgroundColor from NSArray

Tags: objective-c

I have an UIScrollView where I want to add UIViews with different colors.

I declared my UIColors in NSArray, now the app crashes.

```
for (int x = 0; x < clrs; x++) {

    /// create the thumbnail size
    CGRect rect = clrCell.frame;
    rect.size.height = 40;
    rect.size.width = 40;
    rect.origin.x = cx;
    rect.origin.y = 0;

    /// add some properties to thumbnail image
    clrCell = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    clrCell.backgroundColor = [colorPack objectAtIndex:x];

    [clrCell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    clrCell.tag = x;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [clrCell addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];


    [_clrsVIEW addSubview:clrCell];

    cx += clrCell.frame.size.width+1;


}
```

and here is my NSArray:

```
 colorPack = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];", @"[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];", nil];
```

any ideas, how to set background colors from NSArray for an UIView?

Comment: Looks like you found it and should answer your own question. Of course you are correct, you don't need @"..." around the UIColor in your array declaration!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current method is saving the colors as strings, here's a way:

```
colors = @[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0], [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0] ];
```

I tend to prefer the array literal syntax, but if you'd like to stick with your current way:

```
colorPack = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0], [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0], nil];
```